# Programmatically change the weight of a form element

Tags: 7, forms

I have a user activation/registration form with different attribute like

Captcha and security questions which are coming from different modules.

I want to change the display order of form elements.

and i am using this code in my custom module

```
function security_question_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form_id == "create_account_form") {
    $form['#pre_render'][] = 'security_question_form_alter_weight';
  }
}

function security_question_form_alter_weight($elements) {
  $elements['questions']['#weight']= -47; 
  return $elements; 
}
```

It's not working. Can any one have any solution?

Comment: A quick thought here, I think $element is passed by reference so you should add & before it and no need for the return statement

Comment: @IsmailCherri No, as the documentation says *The function(s) provided in #pre_render receive the element as an argument and must return the altered element.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this directly inside `hook_form_alter`, like this:

```
function security_question_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['questions']['#weight'] = -47;
}
```

Then there is no need to create a custom function to do it.

Another thing, you can't implement `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter` and then use `$form_id` inside that. You must implement either `hook_form_alter`, and check if the form id is the one you want, or implement `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter` and write the form id in the function name.